# Three.js lookat seems to be flipped

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have a demo of what I mean here: [Test Site](http://www.myuplay.com/game/test.html) or ([Backup](http://direct.myuplay.com/game/test.html))

For some reason, even though the mouse vector is correct my object is rotated by 90 degrees always in favor of the positive Y axis. The only call that this could be going wrong, as far as I can tell, in is the call: `ship.mesh.lookAt(mouse);`, I call this every time the screen is animated.

Can anyone tell me what to do to fix this and why it is doing it?

Comment: Note: My demo has since been lost to a drive failure and lack of interest to recreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object.lookAt( position )` orients the object so that the object's local positive *z-axis* points toward the desired position.

Your "ship's" front points in the direction of the local positive *y-axis*.

EDIT:

To re-orient your geometry, apply a matrix right after the geometry is created, like so:

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI / 2 ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I change an objects local rotation so that when I use lookat, the point of the ship will point at the mouse?

Comment: I found a [solution](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1958) on three.js issues. Thank you for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: How does the "solution" you found differ from the solution in the answer above?

Comment: It doesn't, but found that solution before checking back here. The funny thing is you wrote both. Thank you for your help!