# Three.js Get Object-relative Local orientation of a scene vector with given World orientation coordinates

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, rotation

I have a given vector V in a scene.  The vector is defined by World Coordinates (VWx,VWy,VWz).  Note that it is a direction vector NOT a position vector.

In the scene I also have an Object3D with random orientation (and position).

I wish to find the local (i.e. relative to the Object3D) coordinates (VLx,VLy,VLz) of the direction vector V .

I have tried the following code (extrapolating from WestLangley's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641875/three-js-how-to-find-world-orientation-vector-of-objects-local-up-vector)) but it doesn't seem to give the right results.

```
var VW = new THREE.Vector3(10,20,30); 
var VL = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0); 

givenObject.updateMatrixWorld();

var ob_WorldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(); 
ob_WorldQuaternion  = givenObject.getWorldQuaternion();

var ob_InvWorldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(); 
ob_InvWorldQuaternion = ob_WorldQuaternion.inverse();

VL = VW.applyQuaternion( ob_InvWorldQuaternion);
```

EDIT(1) Note that the THREE.js Object3D method .worldToLocal(vector) is not suitable because that is just for converting position vectors, not direction vectors.

EIDT(2) [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveow/9a5465p6/4/) illustrates an example application.    The green cone is a child of the green box.  The app is trying to keep the green cone pointing in the same world direction as the white world cone.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15873996/1697459) is your issue?

Comment: @Wilt - Thx for suggestion but I'm not sure about that question and I definitely don't understand the answer given enough to apply it (in three.js) .

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you want to achieve. There might be easier ways to get to your end goal? What is the source of this direction vector?

Comment: @Wilt.  I just want to make a general function of the form VL = F_get_LocalDirectionVector_relativeTo_Object3D_of_WorldDirectionVector (givenObject, VW).  For example VW = world direction of the wind and Object3D = a randomly-oriented wind turbine and so VL is the wind direction relative to the turbine's xyz axes.

Comment: @Wilt I think that the original code worked OK but I was applying the result wrongly.  See my answer.  Thanks for your input and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

(An improved version of my earlier answer).

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hoawrkn/) illustrates 3 ways of aligning child cones.

Red cone has fixed orientation relative to its parent box.

Green cone is aligned so that its' z-axis is aligned to the white world cone.

Blue cone has its' XYZ axes co-aligned with the XYZ axes of the white world cone.

CODE (from the init function):-

```
cone_geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 40, 120, 40, 10, false);

//... The following mod is as recommended by WestLangley's answer at:-
//... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757483/three-js-lookat-seems-to-be-flipped
//... cone.LookAt(PosX) will then point the cone Z-axis towards PosX
//... (assuming cone.position and PosX are relative to the same coordinate system).

cone_geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI / 2 ) );
```

CORE CODE (from the update/animate function):-

```
    worldCone.lookAt(target.position); 

    var worldVec =  new THREE.Vector3();
    worldVec.copy(target.position).sub(worldCone.position);

    worldBox.rotation.x += 0.01;
    worldBox.rotation.y += 0.03;
    worldBox.rotation.z += 0.02;

    var localVec =  new THREE.Vector3();
    localVec = F_get_LocalDirectionVector_relativeTo_Object3D_of_WorldDirectionVector 
( worldBox, worldVec, localVec) ;

    //=================================================================
    function F_get_LocalDirectionVector_relativeTo_Object3D_of_WorldDirectionVector 
( givenObject, WDV, LDV)
          {
              givenObject.updateMatrixWorld(); 

             //FLABBY method: - works but verbose and excessive object creation
             /*
              var ob_InvWorldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(); 
              ob_InvWorldQuaternion = ob_WorldQuaternion.inverse(); 
              LDV.copy( WDV ).applyQuaternion( ob_InvWorldQuaternion );        
              */

              //LEAN method: copies WDV value into LDV 
              //then applies inverse world quaternion of givenObject.

              LDV.copy( WDV )
              .applyQuaternion( 
              givenObject.getWorldQuaternion().inverse() 
              );  

              return LDV;
      } 
      //=================================================================

//... Apply localVec 
//... Get the localCone_G to point in the direction of the LocalVec

 var localCone_G_target_pos = new THREE.Vector3();

 //... LHS becomes sum of two RHS vectors
 localCone_G_target_pos.addVectors( localCone_G.position, localVec );

//... ORIENT THE CHILD CONES

//...Cone_R has fixed orientation relative to parent cube
localCone_R.lookAt(1,0,0); 

//... Cone_G has z-vector pointing in the same direction as world cone
localCone_G.lookAt(localCone_G_target_pos); 

//... Cone_B has its' xyz axes aligned with the world cone
localCone_B.lookAt(1,0,0);
localCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldBox.getWorldQuaternion().inverse()  ); 
localCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldCone.quaternion );
```